# Pb with PATH declare as an environment variable

Tags: namespaces, cygwin, environment-variables

It is my first Post here so let me say Hello to the stackoverflow community before starting !

Here is my Problem :

- i want to declare a PATH as an environment variable in Cygwin
- then i want to be able to use this variable in any command
- the difficulties comes when i have space character in the PATH

Here is what i try without sucess :

```
$ export MYPATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/
$ echo $MYPATH
$ /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/
$ cd $MYPATH
$ bash: cd: /cydrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

i get excatly the same Error with all those various synthax

```
$ export MYPATH="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/"
```

idem with this one

```
$ export MYPATH=$MYPATH"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/"
```

I have no more ideas ... so if you guys can help me , it would be great !

Cheers

sk

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes around `$MYPATH` the same as you would if you were use `cd` while typing out the path manually.

```
cd "$MYPATH"
```

is equivalent to

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/"
```

Notice that the escape character `'\'` for the space is removed when you are setting `$MYPATH` so when `$MYPATH` is expanded for `cd`, the space is no longer escaped. Also note, cygwin doesn't like it if you try to escape the escape character too:

```
export MYPATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\\\ Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/
```

This will actually expand to

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/
```

but cygwin will yell at you for trying to use a MS-DOS style path.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave ! It works perfectly ! And You're Right i also try the \\\ syntax and it doesn't work !